# Flutter iOS distribution fails with No architectures in the binary

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I've been building a flutter application and its come time to release to internal testers and I've been running into issues. The error I get is this

```
ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable."
Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable."
The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
```

I've read many articles online and the main answer is that there is something wrong with my Info.plist. I've had a successful build of this project in the early phases before most of my code and packages were integrated into the project and had a successful build. I've checked my plist with that commit and nothing major has changed other than adding more to the podfile. I've tweaked with them all, including copying over the ios folder from a brand new flutter project and I'm still having issues. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my pod integration?
here is my podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

and here is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 2.0.0+2

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.0 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.12
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.6.0
  dots_indicator: ^2.1.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  flutter_redux: ^0.9.0
  graphql: ^5.0.0
  jwt_decoder: ^2.0.1
  redux: ^5.0.0
  http: ^0.13.4
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.2
  mockito: ^5.0.17
  json_serializable: ^6.1.4
  json_annotation: ^4.4.0
  freezed: ^1.1.1
  freezed_annotation: ^1.1.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  arrow_path: ^2.0.0
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.7

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets: 
    - assets/


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

and lastly my flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on macOS 11.6.4 20G417 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming (hoping) you got this fixed, but in my case the issue happened because of a mismatch between information in my ios/Runner/info.plist and ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist.

What I did to fix the issue:

- Erase/Reset iOS Simulator.
- Close iOS Simulator.
- Delete both files mentioned above.
- Run > flutter create .     to renegerate the files.
- Open **ios** folder with Xcode to check if the information is correct regarding your Apple Settings (use [Fluter Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios) as a guideline). Ex. Deployment target, signatures, etc.
- Run > flutter clean
- Run `flutter pub get`
- Open iOS Simulator
- Run `flutter run`

If any other errors arise, don't panic, simply fix them (one by one) and run it again. My error was trying to fix many different errors at the same time and getting new errors as a result.

Just see the process as TDD (Test Driven **Deployment**) and everything is going to be okay.